# How to download/convert multiple streams to multiple outputs with FFmpeg?

Tags: file, ffmpeg, stream, output

Let's say I have 20 different online stream videos (playlist.m3u8) and I want every video to output to their own .avi files. How can I do that in single file, so I don't have to download and convert every single one separately?

I found a -map command online, but didn't get straight answer to this.

Will this be a working code?

```
ffmpeg -i 1playlist.m3u8 -vf scale=768:-1 -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 -acodec copy -map 0 1.avi \
-i 2playlist.m3u8 -vf scale=768:-1 -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 -acodec copy -map 1 2.avi \
-i 3playlist.m3u8 -vf scale=768:-1 -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 -acodec copy -map 2 3.avi
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but don't know the efficiency with so many parallel encodes. Better route is to write a batch script and iterate through the 20 playlists.

Comment: That -map thing didn't work

Comment: Show full console output.

Comment: I managed to get over one problem, and then another one showed up. Before it didn't "find" the ffmpeg, I had to define a folder where it is. Now it makes an error "Data stream encoding not supported yet (only streamcopy)"

My code looks like this:
bin\ffmpeg -i http://nelonenmedia-ondemand02.nelonenmedia.fi/09/online/video/video_episode_115100809_201603310042.smil/playlist.m3u8 -preset veryfast -qscale:v 1 -crf 18 -vf scale=768:-1 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -map 0 "Ninjago\5.avi" \
etc...

Comment: Replace `-map 0` with `-map 0:v -map 0:a`

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working!